# unable to start the app for mediaPlayer.onPreparedListener

Tags: android

error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to OnPreparedListener

mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

Comment: Add some code and more details

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Activity `implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener`